# International Inheritance

Tags: translations

Going through an international inheritance and need certified documents, including apostilles translated from English to Spanish.
How does one get this completed/by who?

Comment: Who or what entity needs this translation and certification? What requirements do they set?

Comment: What country are you at? What country are the documents from?